# Convert BatchStage<List<Object>> to BatchStage<Object> in Hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

In my hazelcast jet application I am performing grouping joins after that I am getting result in
BatchStage<List> format but I want to convert it to BatchStage, I have tried flatMap but it overwrites some keys that I don't want I want all Object to be stored individually.

My Code:

```
BatchStage<Object> bd = jdbcBatchStageData.flatMap(list -> Traversers.traverseArray(list.toArray()));
```

I know flatMap will replace some keys but How can I store all Object individually in BatchStage so they don't get override any keys.

Object is equal to Map<String, Object>.

Comment: What do you mean by "flatMap will replace some keys"? The output of `flatMap` will contain exactly as many elements as there are in all the input lists.

Comment: You should use `flatMap(list -> Traversers.traverseIterable(list))`, but it doesn't affect the semantics, only uses less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the form of your data (which you don't provide), here's a proposal that might need some tweaking:

```java
jdbcBatchStageData.flatMap(list -> Traversers.traverseArray(list.toArray()))
  .groupingKey(ByKey)
  .aggregate(AggregateOperations.toList())
```

1. Flat maps the different lists into individual items
2. Group by key (you need to define `ByKey` function`
3. Aggregate the result, so you'd a batch of `Map.Entry<K, List>`

Comment: but I don't want to group it I already grouped it and got result in Batch<List<Object>> now I just want to convert it to Batch<Object>

Comment: Your initial problem is how to "unduplicate" your items. If you "just" want to convert, then you just traverse as per your initial code